# Example of a $T_2$ non metric topological space (if possible).

Tags: general-topology

I´m looking for an example of a metric topological space $X$
 and a continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$
where $Y$  is Hausdorff but not metric.

I'm wondering because my professor and I were studying the quotient topology. We were on: $X$ metric and $X/-$ Hausdorff, then $X/-$ metric. So then we asked ourselves if there was an example like the one above, but we left it because we where gonna study other stuff. So I´m still wondering.

Comment: Why are you looking for it? That would help people write answers that are more useful.

Comment: That is what you wrote above. You left out two key pieces of information on this site: (1) where did you encounter the question, and (2) what attempts have you already made? The question looks like a homework problem, frankly, and the goal of this site is not to simply answer homework. You can edit the question to improve it by adding the context behind the question, if it is not homework, and what you have already tried.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, f surjective.

Comment: @EricWofsey My profesor and I where studying the quotient topology. We where on: X metric and X/-  Hausdorff, then X/- metric. So then we asked ourselves if there was if there was an example like the one above, but we left it because we where gonna study other stuff. So I´m still wondering.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example where $f$ is a quotient map.  Let $X=[0,1]\times\mathbb{N}$, and let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $X$ given by $(x,n)\sim(y,m)$ iff either $(x,n)=(y,m)$ or $x=y=0$.  Consider the quotient space $Y=X/{\sim}$ and the quotient map $f:X\to Y$.  Then $Y$ is Hausdorff but not metrizable, because it is not first-countable.  (To prove it is not first-countable, suppose you have countably many open neighborhoods of the equivalence class $[(0,0)]\in Y$, and use a diagonalization argument to construct a new open neighborhood that does not contain any of them.)

Comment: I think it's useful to say that $Y$ is just a graph with one vertex connected to every other by an edge, and no other edges. This is also a good example how a topology on a graph which is not locally finite can be pretty weird.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ be the (Tychonoff) product of an uncountable family of nontrivial Hausdorff spaces, e.g., two-point discrete spaces. $Y$ is Hausdorff because any product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff. $Y$ is not metrizable because it is not first-countable. Let $X$ be a discrete space with the same cardinality as $Y$ and let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjection; then $X$ is metrizable and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly not true that if $X$ is metric and $X / R$ is a quotient of $X$ (in the quotient topology) such that $X / R$ is Hausdorff, that $X / R$ is metrisable.

A classical example of this is taking $X$ as the reals (usual topology) and $R$ the equivalence relation such that $xRy$ iff $x = y$ or $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ (identifying the integers to a point). This is not first countable at the class of the integers, but is Hausdorff.

Comment: This is essentially the same example as the one given by @EricWofsey.

Comment: @tomasz Indeed. It's essentially the simplest example: classes should be closed for being $T_1$ and we have 1 non-trivial class. It it were compact, the result would be metrisable (perfect image of metric space), so we need a closed non-compact set.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want $f$ to be a quotient mapping, then you can easily construct a meta-example, in the spirit of @bof's example.

Let $Y$ be your favourite Hausdorff, non-metrisable space, and let $X$ be $Y$ with discrete topology. Then the "identity" mapping $X\to Y$ works. Of course, it will never be a quotient mapping.

As an aside, what you are contemplating is true if you assume in addition that $X$ is compact. This is because in this case, $X$ is second-countable and $f$ is a closed mapping. This implies that $f[X]$ is also second-countable (because the image of a basis of closed sets in $X$ forms a basis in $f[X]$) and compact, and hence metrisable.